# MYSQL Query using AND OR

Tags: mysql

I have a query where I need to select rows where the a I'm checked if 2 fields are newer than a timestamp that I am providing. I need to provide the result if either or both the fields are newer.

In my mind this is how I think that it should work, but I know that you can't have "AND OR" is there some other command that should be using?

```
SELECT pid 
from   parts 
WHERE  ( lastupdate > '2011-11-29 17:30:57' ) 
       AND OR (othertimestamp > '2011-11-29 17:30:57')
```

Comment: If only one of the conditions need to be true then you just need to use `OR`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just OR that you want

```
SELECT pid 
from   parts 
WHERE  (lastupdate > '2011-11-29 17:30:57') 
OR     (othertimestamp > '2011-11-29 17:30:57')
```

If you want to show which if one or both satisfied the condition you could add this

```
SELECT pid , 
       CASE
            WHEN  lastupdate > '2011-11-29 17:30:57' AND othertimestamp > '2011-11-29 17:30:57'  THEN 'both'
            WHEN lastupdate > '2011-11-29 17:30:57' THEN 'lastupdate'
            WHEN othertimestamp > '2011-11-29 17:30:57' THEN 'othertimestamp'
       END as which_field

FROM   parts 
WHERE  (lastupdate > '2011-11-29 17:30:57') 
OR     (othertimestamp > '2011-11-29 17:30:57')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `OR` - `1 OR 1` still returns true. It's not exclusive OR, which would be `XOR`. In your case, `AND OR` is simply `OR`.